# how to pass operators dynamically to if condition

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, custom-report-type

[image]

I am trying to implement multiple filters on visual force page to generate custom reports by using external system data from rest call.I am not going to store anything in salesforce objects.So i have to do search by looping throught data

like

```
if(searchField1=searchVal1 && searchField2=searchVal2 || searchField3=searchVal3)){
    system.debug('***'+criteria matched);
}
```

but the problem is i have to change the && and || operators according to user selection from drop-down like if user selects OR and And in dropdown it has to chnage as

```
if(searchField1=searchVal1 || searchField2=searchVal2 && searchField3=searchVal3)){
    system.debug('***'+criteria matched);
}
```

so i was wondering is there any way to achieve this dynamically...

like

```
if(searchField1=searchVal1 'operator1' searchField2=searchVal2 'operator2' searchField3=searchVal3)){
        system.debug('***'+criteria matched);
    }
```

happy to hear any changes in the code...

Comment: If you check some similar Salesforce UI its a bit more involved than you show. Its unclear whether your screen represents `(a && b) || c` or `a && (b || c)`.

Comment: @KeithC (a & &  b) || c in this case... I too feel there are too many complications here... For time being I was struggling to pass operators dynamically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the issue  mention in the comment, you can create methods that allow this sort of code:

```
if (op(searchField1 == searchVal1, operator1, searchField2 == searchVal2) ...
```

where the method would be:

```
private Boolean op(Boolean b1, String operator, Boolean b2) {
    return operator == 'and' ? (b1 && b2) : (b1 || b2);
}
```

Comment: Seems to be this was the best thing I have come across... Thanks @keith C

Comment: this is working perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

Without copy-pasting the answer, you'll want to make a Boolean tree (B-Tree), and parse it all the way through. I started writing an answer, and then I realized that there's already a perfectly good answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568067/how-to-parse-a-boolean-expression-and-load-it-into-a-class). The only difference is there's some translation you'll have to do going from C# to Apex Code, which should be trivial.

Comment: And now I feel like writing one... I might be back.

Comment: sure... it would be really great...